# Jasper iReport - how to hide pie chart label border?

Tags: ireport

Is it possible to hide the black border of pie chart labels  in iReport ?. I want to keep the values but not the black border. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the direct property on ireport, but you can do a customizer on the PieChar like in the example:

http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/chart-customizers-1/